# brightness control with ddcci and gnome slider

Tags: brightness, backlight

I have connected an external touch to my mini pc. DDCCI module seems to work for me.

eg

```
echo 90 > /sys/class/backlight/ddcci5/brightness
```

results in a change of brightness. But unfortunately I cannot use the slider. The slider still controls `intel_backlight`. How can I change the slider to ddcci5? Is there a way to suppress the intel device to be populated during startup? acpi_brightness=none didn't work out.

Thanks for any hint

Comment: This seems to be a [known bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/-/issues/527), which is unfortunately still open at this time.

Comment: This has been reported as a [bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/-/issues/527).